# Relative velocity from points' point of view

Tags: physics, classical-mechanics

**Edit:** The terminology might be imprecise. Please pay attention to the picture I drew to explain my problems. I will appreciate an edit that will ensure the terminology is no longer disputable.

This must be a simple problem but I can't figure an equation for it. Consider two moving points, $A$ and $B$. We know their positions and velocities, but we want to observe them from $A$'s point of view. I will make examples in 1D, but I need to solve this problem in two dimensions.

What I know is that relative *position* can be calculated by subtraction:

$$pos_{relA} = pos_B - pos_A$$

Relative velocity depends on position. This image illustrates it:

[image: image description]

You can see that albeit the velocities of the objects are same on both images, the relative velocity is different. Relative velocity clearly depends on relative position of the two objects. Relative velocity between two points is also same for both of the points.

In my image, relative velocity is positive when distance between points is increasing. That's not necessary.

How to calculate relative velocity of two points?

Comment: Not sure about the tags, but I don't think this is physycs question.

Comment: It involves velocities, which are a physical phenomenon.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are looking for is the derivative of the distance between points with respect to time, that is their relative [*radial* velocity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radial_velocity). If $r=\sqrt{(x_B-x_A)^2}$ then
$$
v_{rel}={dr\over dt}={(x_B-x_A)\cdot(v_B-v_A)\over r}.
$$
Notice that this also works if $x_A$ and $x_B$ are vectors: in that case you have a dot product in the numerator.

Comment: Thank you! This looks promising. However is it necessary to know $r$ to calculate the distance derivative? I am asking because calculating distance is computationally intensive, and I am going to use this math in game implementation.

Comment: If your points move along a straight line then notice that $|x_B-x_A|/r=1$, so you just need to compute the sign of $x_B-x_A$ and multiply it by $v_B-v_A$.

Comment: Thanks. I wish I could upvote once more :)

Answer (score 1):

The velocity of $A$ relative to $B$ is $$\underline{v}_A-\underline{v}_B$$

Note that the velocities must be expressed in vector form

Comment: How is that useful to know how fast does A more relative to B? All this gives you is the difference in their speeds, but not the relative speed between the two objects?

Comment: Speed is the magnitude of the velocity vector. Relative speed is the magnitude of the relative velocity vector

Answer (score 0):

Velocity is the derivative of position with respect to time, and relative velocity is the derivative of relative position with respect to time. So differentiate your formula for the relative position of B with respect to A: $\frac{d pos_{relA}}{dt} = \frac{d pos_B}{dt} - \frac{d pos_A}{dt}$. So the relative velocity is simply the difference in velocities, just like relative position is the difference in positions.

Comment: My image clearly shows that relative velocity is **not** just difference in velocities, because depending on the points' position, their relative velocity varies.

Comment: What you want is the rate of change of the distance between A and B, which is not the same as the relative velocity of B with respect to A.

Comment: What is relative velocity then, if not the velocity of B as seen by A?

Comment: In your picture the velocity of B as seen by A is the same in both cases. You can see that B is moving in the same direction in both instances. Suppose that A is stationary at the origin. By your argument, if B is moving toward the right its velocity has a different sign depending on whether it's on the left or right side of the origin. Does that make sense?

Comment: Yes, that's what I need.

Comment: What you seem to want to compute is the time derivative of $|pos_B-pos_A|$. This is not nearly as nice to calculate, especially in more than one dimension. It's also not defined when A and B are in the same position.